# Java Swing - Get object that the mouse hovers over

Tags: java, swing

I have a JList and want to change the tooltips, depending on the entry the mouse hovers over. I tried searching my problem on google, but had no success.

Basically i need to get the object i am currently hovering over.

Every help is appreciated

Comment: A am a newbie, but tell me this: won't mouse over help? the function that what happens when a mouse points over it

Comment: @DakshShah talkign about java here, not javascript ;)

Comment: Even i am talking about java

Comment: @JohannesH. I use netbeans, in there the thing that we do right click the object and go to event and action performed

Comment: @DakshShah That's only possible if you use some graphical GUI builder. Most programmer's don't, 'cause you got better control if you code it yourself.

Comment: yes, i do everything by hand

Comment: Saying "I tried searching with google" is no substitute to actually searching with google or official documentation: http://bit.ly/1byD7gm http://bit.ly/1byDac4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you have to extend JList and expose the tooltip text method. Here is an example program I found sometime ago using Google:

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// Custom class to extend our JList and expose tooltip functionality.
class MyList extends JList {

    public MyList() {
        super();

        // Attach a mouse motion adapter to let us know the mouse is over an item and to show the tip.
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                MyList theList = (MyList) e.getSource();
                ListModel model = theList.getModel();
                int index = theList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                if (index > -1) {
                    theList.setToolTipText(null);
                    String text = (String) model.getElementAt(index);
                    theList.setToolTipText(text);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Expose the getToolTipText event of our JList
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
        return super.getToolTipText();
    }
}

public class TestJList extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestJList myTest = new TestJList();
                myTest.setTitle("Example JList");
                myTest.setSize(300, 300);
                myTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                MyList list = new MyList();

                // Create our model and add some items.
                DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

                model.addElement("one");
                model.addElement("two");
                model.addElement("three");
                model.addElement("four");

                // Set the model for our list
                list.setModel(model);

                ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(list);

                // Add our custom list and show the form.
                MyTest.add(list);
                MyTest.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, but there is no need for the MouseListener. Just override the getToolTipText(...) method (ie. the code from the `mouseMoved()` method should basically be moved to the `getTooTipText()` method).

Answer (score 3):

1) Assign a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to all elements in question.
2) Implement the [`mouseEntered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseEntered%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method
3) Inside that method, use [`event.getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) to get the element that was hovered.

Comment: yeah i found this solution myself right now. but thanks i will try this

Comment: -1 for reinventing the wheel. JList already supports tool tips. Just override the getToolTipText(...) method of JList. Or you can also use a custom renderer which set the tool tip text. Also, a mouseEntered event is NOT generated for each item of a JList, which is the requirement.

Comment: @camickr you are right according to that i will get trouble finding the specific item of the list. do you have a suggestion ? i mean could you explain "overriding gettooltiptext" a bit more in detail ?

Comment: @user2664856, look at the answer given by sanjeev. The code in the `mouseMoved` method should basically be moved to the `getToolTipText()` method.