# Check component under mouse

Tags: java, swing

I used SWING in desktop Java project.

Is possible to check what type of component is under mouse ?

For example: 
I have got many different components and I want put mouse on and get what component is under(ex. JButton, ComboBox etc). It is possible ?

I do not want add mouse listener to all components. Maybe there is way to add mouse listener on whole panel... ?

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800442/java-swing-get-object-that-the-mouse-hovers-over

Comment: Can you explain your aversion to adding a MouseListener to every Component? All you need is 1 MouseAdapter with the MouseEntered / MouseExited methods filled out added to all of your components. What's so burdensome?

Comment: It is burdensome because I have thousands components in many different panels and instead of adding MouseListeners to all Components I think about something like verify Component under mouse. It is possible without using MouseAdapter on Panels which contains this Components ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not want add mouse listener to all components

You can use an `AWTEventListener` to listen for all events that are generated.

Check out [Global Event Listeners](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for an example to listen for MouseEvents and KeyEvents.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

I used event `AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK` and AWTEventListener as @ Eric Bischoff says.

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

                Log(button.getText());
            }
        }
    }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

And it works great, with using `e.getSource()` I get component on which event is active, check if it is instance of JButton, next cast to JButton and can do nice things, for example actionPerformed on this button (do not waste time to click it by `button.doClick()`). I do this for optimization my application, because `button.doClick()` cost about 80~ms, but when we actionPerformed on event from this button this cost is 0ms (time from delegate to action of listener on this button).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to this question.

**1. Get Mouse Events**

As @carmickr said, use the AWTEventListener like so `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, eventMask)` and use an event mask to filter just mouse events.

**2. Check Components for Mouse**

You'll need to get all of the components in your GUI's component hierarchy and check to see if the mouse is inside of each one. The one that is nested the deepest is where the mouse is at. Here is a way to get all of the components if it helps:

```
public static List<Component> getAllComponents(final Container c) {
    Component[] comps = c.getComponents();
    List<Component> compList = new ArrayList<Component>();
    for (Component comp : comps) {
        compList.add(comp);
        if (comp instanceof Container)
            compList.addAll(getAllComponents((Container) comp));
    }
    return compList;
}
```

Following these two steps will ensure that you are not conflicting with any other event handlers that may be in use.

Comment: Ok but how get all Components in Panel ? All components are on Panel, I do not have any lists of components. How get this Container from my Panel ? I want turn on listening, get JButton object and turn off listening.

Comment: I accept Yours answer because was wortwhile :) I post my solution of get JButton on do action on them